# Zoo lag diff back in data frame

Tags: r

I want to place the results of a lagged diff back into my data frame. It means I would have leading NAs for the different lags.

I am using:

```
new.df$lag1 <- diff(new.df$Close, lag = 1, differences = 1, arithmetic = TRUE, na.pad = TRUE)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, lag1, value = c(0.248860000000001,  : 
  replacement has 6177 rows, data has 6178
```

I thought that if it said na.pad=TRUE then this would place a NA on row 1 and the lag diff on row 2. This is not the case.

heres some sample data:

```
data <- c(10,15,89,40,55,67,79)

lag1 <- diff(data, lag = 1, differences = 1, arithmetic = TRUE, na.pad = TRUE)
```

goal is to place this back into the dataframe... with leading NA's depending on number of lags.

Answer (score 2):

```
dta = c(10,15,89,40,55,67,79)

require(zoo)

apply(lag(zoo(dta), c(-1,0), na.pad = TRUE), 1L, diff)

#> apply(lag(zoo(dta), c(-1,0), na.pad = TRUE), 1L, diff)
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
# NA   5  74 -49  15  12  12
```

Also, try to avoid naming your objects with names already used by base R (like `data`)!

---

On May 10th 2018 [it was pointed to me by @thistleknot (thanks!) that `dplyr` masks `stats`'s own `lag` generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638529/zoo-lag-diff-back-in-data-frame/45639642?noredirect=1#comment87540599_45639642). Therefore make sure you don't have `dplyr` attached, or instead run `stats::lag` explicitly, otherwise my code won't run.

> I think I found the culprit: github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1586
>   answer: This is a natural consequence of having lots of R packages.
>   Just be explicit and use stats::lag or dplyr::lag

Comment: used your answer above on dta... Error: `n` must be a nonnegative integer scalar, not double of length 2

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45642435/rolling-lagged-differences

Comment: "Error: n must be a nonnegative integer scalar,"  I have the same issue at home, but had it working at work... hrm...

Comment: @thistleknot I have it working on R x64 3.3.0/3.3.1/3.4.0/3.5.0 on Windows 10. What about you?

Comment: it's odd.  sometimes I get it to work, sometimes I don't.  I suspect somewhere in my script it's unloading the library?  Not sure yet.

Comment: I think I found the culprit: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1586 answer: This is a natural consequence of having lots of R packages. Just be explicit and use stats::lag or dplyr::lag

Comment: @thistleknot WOW. Thanks for this discovery! Ideally `dplyr` should stop masking base generics, but a lot of packages do that. Perhaps CRAN could become more emphatic regarding it. I'll update some of my answers crediting your find. Thanks again!

Comment: @AndrewBannerman Please see the conversation and my edit on why it might not be running on your end.