# Create time event based dummy variable in R - leads & lags

Tags: r, variables, events, time, panel

I am currently searching for a method to create a set of dummy variables indicating a time event in a panel. Explicitly I am trying to make dummy variables indicating the event 20 years prior the event and 20 years after the event, e.g. the effect of a war on trade in 20 years. I want to code this dummy for each parnter in the dyads. How is it possible, to elegantly programm these event dummies ? I would appreciate your help :)

```
   iso_o iso_d year mid_o mid_d
  ABW   AFG 1980     0     1
  ABW   AFG 1981     0     1
  ABW   AFG 1982     0     1
  ABW   AFG 1983     0     2
  ABW   AFG 1984     0     1
  ABW   AFG 1985     0     1
  ABW   AFG 1986     0     1
  ABW   AFG 1987     0     1
  ABW   AFG 1988     0     0
  ABW   AFG 1989     0     1
```

So and this is where I want to go to:

```
   iso_o iso_d year mid_o mid_d mid_o_t-20 mid_o_t-19 mid o_t-18 .... mid_d_t-20 
  ABW   AFG 1980     0     1     0          0           0 
  ABW   AFG 1981     0     1     0          0           0 
  ABW   AFG 1982     0     1     0          0           0 
  ABW   AFG 1983     0     2     0          0           0 
  ABW   AFG 1984     0     1     0          0           0  
  ABW   AFG 1985     0     1     0          0           0
```

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: thank you for helping out though. I found a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here `da.f` (short for `data.frame` with no collision with known functions) follows approximately your structure as you did not include it in the question.

```
library(zoo)
#da.f is randomly generated in this example
da.f = data.frame(mid_o = sample(seq(0,4), 50, replace = TRUE), mid_d = sample(seq(0,4), 50, replace = TRUE))
#our result consists of 20 lags backward and forward in time 
res = lag(as.zoo(da.f), -20:20, na.pad = TRUE)
```

---

On May 10th 2018 [it was pointed to me by @thistleknot (thanks!) that `dplyr` masks `stats`'s own `lag` generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638529/zoo-lag-diff-back-in-data-frame/45639642?noredirect=1#comment87540599_45639642). Therefore make sure you don't have `dplyr` attached, or instead run `stats::lag` explicitly, otherwise my code won't run.

> I think I found the culprit: github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1586
>   answer: This is a natural consequence of having lots of R packages.
>   Just be explicit and use stats::lag or dplyr::lag

Comment: thank you for helping out! Your help had led me in the right direction! I found a solution to my problem. 

ps. since lag and shift only take positive numbers, i had to create lags and leads, adding 2 more lines of code.

Comment: @NikolaiKI well, lag accepts negative and positive input. Alas, my solution requires a single line of code, and the resulting columns are readily named as you wanted. Nonetheless, consider upvoting/accepting it, glad it helped you ;)

Comment: Somehow my R Suite does not want it! I get the error: No negtive integers are accepted. Furthermore I had the problem, that the matrix takes allot of RAM and I am programming on a University PC from 2008. Therefore the data.table method is more convenient. 

ps: unfortunatley I can not upvote it at the momemt : I dont have enough reputation :(

Comment: @NikolaiKl Did you install `zoo`, load it and also convert your timeseries with `as.zoo`?

Comment: @NikolaiKl Here's what it returns for me: https://gist.github.com/bhvieira/92486224815cfd65ef03314a7ee6fea4 Are you really sure no error or warning is thrown when running the code in my answer?

Comment: owh yeah, why should i make this stuff all out ? furthermore the code (including mine) is somehow not giving me the right solution for all dyadic pairs , since conflict data differs and observation for my main variable trade is not registered for all years. I have to get a command with `by` or something like it! but thank you very much for helping out !

Answer (score 0):

Hello There and thank you for your help!

I found the solution to the problem: I had to convert the data.frame to a data.table in the first place. Seconly I found a way to create multiple columns in data.table combining the commands `sprintif` and `shift`. Therby I could create 20 lags and 20 leads within only 4 lines of code.

```
df[, sprintf("mid_o_lag_%0d", 1:20) := shift(mid_o, c(1:20), type = 'lag')]
df[, sprintf("mid_d_lag_%0d", 1:20) := shift(mid_d, c(1:20), type = 'lag')]
df[, sprintf("mid_o_lead_%0d", 1:20) := shift(mid_o, c(1:20), type = 'lead')]
df[, sprintf("mid_d_lead_%0d", 1:20) := shift(mid_d, c(1:20), type = 'lead')]
```